# PHP Remove section of array before a certain key value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that is in a certain order and I want to just cutoff a portion of the array starting from the first index to the index of a given key.

IE...
If i had this array

```
$array = array("0" => 'blue', "1" => 'red', "2" => 'green', "3" => 'red', "4"=>"purple");
```

I want to cut off the first part of the array before the key "2" (as a string) is seen.
So the end array would be something like...

> "2" => 'green'
>   "3" => 'red'
>   "4"=>'purple'

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your case you can use

```
print_r(array_slice($array, 2, count($array),true));
```

EDIT: For edited question

```
$cloneArray = $array;
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  if($key == $givenInex)
     break;

  unset($cloneArray[$key]);
}
```

Then use $cloneArray

Comment: I should've written this code in the first place, really, instead of what I've in my answer. +1 for giving the correct answer :)

Comment: i just edited my post. i should have made clearer that its the index of the string "2" not the 2nd index of the array.

Comment: thank you! this is very helpful ... in my case, I use `array_shift($cloneArray);` instead of `unset($cloneArray[$key]);` because my array not using key names and I want index keep starting from 0

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray = array_slice($array,2,-1,true);
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it will work correctly only when the array is ordered, because it takes offset  + length as arguments, not the start index and end index. If it's not, then you need to do `ksort` first.

Comment: this will not echo the purple

Comment: @meze: I didn't check its output, what I meant was using array_slice in general, not necessarily this *particular* code. Sorry for not being explicit and thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Gaurav: yes, you are right, I'd change this to `count($array)`, but as you've already posted it as an answer, I'll leave it be. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes u have to use array_slice() function in php for ur solution..............

example code is below,

```
`
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$output = array_slice($input, 2);      // returns "c", "d", and "e"
$output = array_slice($input, -2, 1);  // returns "d"
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"

// note the differences in the array keys
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1));
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1, true));
```

`

the above code give u the following output,

**Array
(
    [0] => c
    [1] => d
)
Array
(
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
)**