# How to delete previous all elements from a specified index in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I want to delete previous all elements from the current specified index

For example:

```
$array = [0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c", 3=>"d", 4=>"e"];
```

I have an index like `3`, so I want to delete previous all like

```
0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c"
```

and only have

```
3=>"d", 4=>"e"
```

in my new array.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932151/php-remove-section-of-array-before-a-certain-key-value,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Remove section of array before a certain key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932151/php-remove-section-of-array-before-a-certain-key-value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$array = [0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c", 3=>"d", 4=>"e"];
$output = array_slice($array, 3);
```

output:

```
array(2) {
 [0]=> string(1) "d"
 [1]=> string(1) "e"
}
```

Another solution with saving index

```
$array = [0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c", 3=>"d", 4=>"e"];
$output = array_slice($array, 3, null, true);
```

output:

```
array(2) {
 [3]=> string(1) "d"
 [4]=> string(1) "e"
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Answer (score 5):

You may to use [array_slice()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

In example :

```
<?php
$array = [0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c", 3=>"d", 4=>"e"];

$startingPosition = 3;

//                                                   Preserve keys
//                                                        |
//               Your array     Delete from   Delete to   |
//                     |             |        (if null,   |
//                     |             |        to the end) |
//                     |             |            |       |
//                     v             v            v       v
$array = array_slice($array, $startingPosition , null, true);

var_dump($array);
```

Output :

```
array(2) {
  [3]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "e"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use veriation of [array-slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and so on (as `array_slice($array, 3)` ) but also simple for loop:

```
$array = [0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c", 3=>"d", 4=>"e"];
$copy = false;
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $copy |= ($k == 3);
    if ($copy)
        $res[$k] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use unset() to remove the elements. As shown below.

```
<?php

$array = [0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c", 3=>"d", 4=>"e"];
$index = 3;

for($i = 0; $i<$index; $i++) 
{   unset($array[$i]);  }

echo "<pre>";print_r($array);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$array = [0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c", 3=>"d", 4=>"e"];
$newArray = array_slice($array, 3, NULL, TRUE);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
)
```

> Note that 4 th parameter: TRUE -> preserve_keys is very important.

If it is set to true, preserves the keys in the output array.

Your new array will now have all elements only after index `3`

All elements before `3` are not returned here.

Comment: OP want to keep keys in new array. **and only have 3=>"d", 4=>"e" in my new array**

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php

  $array = [0 => "a", 1 => "b", 2 => "c", 3=>"d", 4=>"e"];

  $new_array = array_slice($array, 3); // 3 is your key to slice

  print_r($new_array);

?>
```